# Function with poles/singularities; Polynomial approximant has no poles

Tags: mathematics, integration, singularities

I don't know if i should ask this question or if it makes too much sense. My knowledge of this topic is quite incomplete, so please bear through with me. Any insights are appreciated.

A function ([Fermi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) to be precise), has poles/singularities which (probably) correspond to resonant frequencies.

We can approximate the Fermi function with Chebyshev polynomials, such that the approximated function does not have poles anymore.

If i integrate over the Fermi function (-Inf to Inf) (such as inside a reservoir correlation function), I can apply the theorem of residues/Jordan's lemma since it has poles, and find the residues and then write the function in terms of summation of residues and so on.

The Chebyshev approximated Fermi function (a very good approximation) has no poles.

My question is: How can a function that has poles equal to a function that does not have any poles? Can their integration yield equal results? Is what I'm saying plain nonsense? If yes, please guide me.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82997/2451

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer is that your Chebyshev polynomial expansion has a finite radius of convergence. If you try to integrate it outside that radius of convergence, you will get nonsense. This is the same as Taylor expanding $1/(1 - x)$ about $x = 0$ -- the resulting series diverges for $|x| \geq 1$. Lionelbrits suggested the way around this is a Laurent series, and pointed you to a reference on these. But the reason for the contradiction is that you are looking at a series expansion that does not converge in part of the region you are interested in.

Comment: could you suggest a way around the problem?

Comment: "But the reason for the contradiction is that you are looking at a series expansion that does not converge in part of the region you are interested in." could you please elaborate on this. what effect should it have(if any)?

Comment: The way around the problem is a Laurent expansion, or some other expansion that converges everywhere. As an example of where this comes from, plot the Taylor series for $1/(1+x)$ and look at it near $x = 1$ -- it starts to blow up!  That's because you're outside the radius of convergence for the series. You've chosen to represent your function in a basis set that does not describe the function everywhere.

Comment: okay. so Chebyshev expansion is no good? actually we already used Laurent expansion. It had it's flaws, so we decided to move to Chebyshev. I think it should work _somehow_. It's known to work..

Comment: Could you post a link to where it's known to work?

Comment: I have a paper, i'm currently reading it: An efficient solution of Liouville-von Neumann equation that is applicable to zero and finite temperatures.

Comment: In this case it doesn't look like they're expanding the Fermi distribution in the basis. It appears in Eq. 6 as a weight factor on a density matrix. It's been years since I looked at this kind of stuff, so I'm not sure how helpful I can be beyond that. But if you tell us why you're expanding the Fermi distribution in some basis we might find a better way around.

Comment: For exactly the reason the paper does it for. It's what my research is on. Newton polynomials was also an option. But I went with chebyshev first, but apparently, it's fundamentally wrong to do it this way because of the pole/no pole situation. So now I'm going to try and see if what this paper^ does to see if that would work. If you have any reservations about this, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely, a function may have a [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) in some region that has terms that go like $(z-a)^n$ for both positive and negative $n$. The negative $n$ terms are the poles, and far away from $z=a$ these terms may be small. You pick up their contribution when you integrate, because of the residue theorem, but otherwise two functions may be equal in some neighbourhood but not share poles elsewhere.

Comment: I only somewhat understand what you're explaining. Here's a more detailed question I posted earlier. Do you have any views on it?
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82997/applying-theorem-of-residues-to-a-correlation-function-where-the-fermi-function